# Share files between RedHat and Mac

Tags: rhel, macintosh, shared-disk

I have one RedHat 6 machine and three Mac OS machines. I want the RedHat one to be a file server, so that all files will be stored there. All Mac clients will access this server according to their rights.

It seems that this will not use samba. Could you please let me know what should I do in this case?

Comment: Why won't it use Samba?

Comment: i just don't know if Samba can use to share file from Redhat to Mac or not as i am using Mac Os 10.7.4

Comment: Samba works just fine (but differently) with *nix-to-*nix.

Comment: What do you mean by [work just fine but differently]? i don't know much about networking setting. so would you please help to describe more detail

Comment: Google is your friend for this, your question is too large and you need to read some substantial tutorials. You could use either samba or nfs to do what you're envisaging. I would use nfs, if all the machines are on a single local network and behind a firewall. But even choosing between nfs and samba here is a large topic.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just three clients you could configure your redhat machine as an ftp server or use sftp (http://docs.ocf.berkeley.edu/wiki/SFTP_mount_in_Mac_OS_X). Each machine would need to be associated with a unique user account on the the red hat machine. I would not use this approach if you plan to have many machines but for 3 machines this should be "good enough".

Comment: Thank David for your advice, but thinking of the extend in the future, i would try Samba or NFS as Dubiousjim suggested.I am looking for some article on these two settings. i installed Webmin